# custom operators with special characters in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, operator-overloading

I know custom operators are not officialy supported by c++.
And I already know [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31783/Custom-User-Defined-Operators-in-C) to define custom operators.
But since this doesnt seem to work for custom operators containing special characters I would like to know if there is any safe method or hack for creating custom operators with special characters (like `<-` or `#`) in c++

Comment: In your particular example, you might be able to do something gross by overloading `<` and `-` operators.  But in general, no.

Comment: Why not overload an existing operator? Is there really no existing operator that does something similar to what you want to do?

Comment: So there is absolute no way?

Answer (score 3):

```
struct A {
  int x;
};

template<class T>
struct dashed {
  T t;
  template<class U>
  operator U()&&{ return -std::move(t); }
};

template<class T>
dashed<T> operator-(T&& t){return {{std::forward<T>(t)}};}

template<class T>
A& operator<( A& lhs, dashed<T> rhs ) {
  lhs.x = rhs.t.x;
  return lhs;
}

int main() {
  A a{1}, b{2};
  std::cout << a.x << '\n';
  a <- b;
  std::cout << a.x << '\n';
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/403831b2160d7b39).

In general, no.  I just can hack *this particular example* of `<-` by using other operators.